# Sequentialization of a topological space has the same convergent sequences?

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space. We define the sequentialization $\kappa$ of $X$ as the topology $\kappa$ for which a set $A$ is closed iff for every sequence $(x_n)_n$ in $A$ with $x_n\to x$, we have $x\in A$.

Trivially, $\tau \subseteq \kappa$.

Question: Do $\tau$ and $\kappa$ have the same convergent sequences, or equivalently:

If $x_n\to x$ for $\tau$, do we have $x_n\to x$ for $\kappa$?

I'm not sure this is even true, but it sound like something that could be true.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the definition of $\kappa$. How do we know that if $A$ and $B$ are closed w.r.t. $\kappa$ then $A \cup B$ is?

Comment: I understand now. Suppose $x_n \to x$ where each $x_n \in A \cup B$. Then either there is an infinite subsequence $(x_{n_i})$ in $A$, in which case $x_{n_i} \to x \implies x \in A$, or there is an infinite subsequence $(x_{n_i})$ in $B$, in which case $x_{n_i} \to x \implies x \in B$.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk Take a sequence $(x_n)$ in $A \cup B$ with $x_n \to x$. WLOG, there is a subsequence in $A$ and this still converges to $x$, so $x\in A$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.  Suppose $x_n\to x$ with respect to $\tau$, and $U$ is an open neighborhood of $x$ with respect to $\kappa$.  If $x_n\not\in U$ for infinitely many $n$, then these infinitely many $n$ form a subsequence which still converges to $x$.  By definition of $\kappa$, $X\setminus U$ is closed under limits of sequences with respect to $\tau$.  But then since the subsequence is contained in $X\setminus U$, we conclude that $x\in X\setminus U$, which is a contradiction.  Thus all but finitely many $x_n$ are in $U$, as desired.